# UTF-8 in Java Servlet doesn't work when deployed to Azure Websites

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm facing a problem with character encoding. 
Consider this simple snippet:

```
    @Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().println(req.getParameter("test"));
    resp.getWriter().println(Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

When I make a http put request (using chrome's postman app) everything is fine on localhost tomcat:
test parameter: żłąźć

Result:

żłąźć
windows-1250

But when I deploy this servlet to azure websites tomcat, the following test goes wrong:

Result:

Å¼ÅÄÅºÄ
windows-1252

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it. I needed to change server.xml file (placed in apache-tomcat-7.0.52/conf) and added "URIEncoding="UTF-8" to Connector:

```
    <Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```